# How to get a MySQL field's content with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on my website's database and I had this problem recently:
I want the user to read a field of a row, when another field of the same row is submitted.
I.e:

> user_id=1 user_name=Fran user_pass=Potato referedby_id=0 referedby_name=empty
>
> When going inside www.website.com/form.php?referedby_id=1
>
> I want the user to see "So, Fran refered you?"

I've been learning php and I decided to try this:

```
$referedbyid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["referedby_id"]); //In this case it's 1 because of the url

$sel_referedbyname = "select user_name from users where user_id='$referedbyid'"; //Then this should be the select of the user_name "Fran"

$run_referedbyname = mysqli_query($con, $sel_referedbyname); //Then a query for that select

$check_referedbyname = mysqli_fetch_field($run_referedbyname); //And this one the content of the query's result

$refername = $check_refername->user_name; //As the query result is an object I want to convert it to text

if(isset($_POST["register"]) && $check_user == 0 && $check_email == 0 && $pass == $pass2){ //If everything is right and the user/email does not already exist

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_email, user_pass, refer_id, refer_name) VALUES ('$user', '$email', '$pass', '$referid', '$refername')"); //It's submitted to the database with the other values.

mysqli_close($con); //And we finish the connection with the db.
```

The problem is that when I try this and check the database, the referedby_name field is empty. Is it a syntax error? Or is this because it didn't convert to text properly?

In case $referedbyname is not text, how can I convert it properly? Is this because I'm using the fetch_field function wrong?

**Additional info**: $referedbyid is being called properly (I think) in a POST form with this html

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" onsubmit="validate();">

<table width="500" align="center" bgcolor="skyblue">

<tr align="center">

<td colspan="3"><h2>Registrarse</h2></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="right"><b>Nombre de usuario:</b></td>

<td><input type="text" name="user" required="required"/></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="right"><b>Email:</b></td>

<td><input type="email" name="email" required="required"/></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<tr>

<td align="right"><b>Contraseña:</b></td>

<td><input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" required="required"/></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="right"><b>Verificar contraseña:</b></td>

<td><input type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2" required="required"/></td>

</tr>

<tr align="center">
<td colspan="3">
<input type="hidden" name="referedby_id" value="<?php echo $_GET["referedby_id"]; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Registrarse"/></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Comment: `?refer_id` is a GET method yet you're using POST in your query.

Comment: You say "When going inside www.website.com/form.php?refer_id=1" it should produce the name Fran. This is inconsistant with the date you gave. It should either be "refer_id=0" or "user_id=0". Which one did you mean?

Comment: It still doesn't show the refer_name If I use a GET mehod in the query. And what's more, it stops showing the refer_id in the database, as the form's method is POST. I'm almost sure the problem starts on mysqli_fetch_field, I just don't know what it could be.

Comment: @kojow7 Read the php, it selects the user_name (Fran) from the table where user_id (1) = $referid (1). 
Fran's refer_id=0 means Fran was not refered by any user.

Comment: Are there any other required (not null or key) fields in your users table?

Comment: Only these http://puu.sh/i7P0q/e94fe694b0.png

Comment: Also, once you get this working, I highly suggest you change to using prepeared statements, otherwise your database is easily hacked with SQL injection.

Comment: I know, I try to learn how to write the script properly. After it works I use to add a cool css design and security measures. It's a private script for now so I don't have to much to worry about.

Comment: The reason it's not working if I understand what "nulo" means, is because those fields are not allowed to be NULL.  When you are inserting your new record you are only inserting a value for referrer_name, you also need to fill in values for the other fields (except the auto_increment field).

Comment: I am confused, however, why you are trying to insert this name as a new record in the users table, when the name already exists as user_name.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it's more clear now. I want the form to create a new user. This user will be refered by another user's ID. The referer's ID is in the URL, yet the other inputs of the form aren´t. Also, I want the new user to read the name of the person who refered him. I'm not trying to insert his name as a new record, I want the user_name of a person, to be the referedby_name of another one that's signing up to the website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79285/discussion-between-kojow7-and-fraaaan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the downvotes, I tried to be as clear and specific as I could...
Anyways, if someone else has any trouble finding **the value** of a specific field just use `mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conect, $select))['name of the sql field']`

`mysqli_fetch_field($result)` will only show you information about the field, like the type of input, name of the table, name of the column, etc.

Hope that's useful for someone with the same issue. Bye.